# what are the properties of a variable in objective-c that is declared above @interface in a *.h file? (sample attached)

Tags: objective-c

I saw the following in some code (see below). Have not come across the concept of a variable being declared above the @interface.   What is the concept here? / What are the properties of this variable and how it could be used?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSMutableArray* testArray;  // <=== HERE

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
}
@end
```

Comment: Where have you seen this? I have not seen or used it in this position. That variable should go inside the `@interface` scope.

Comment: @WrightsCS: It would do something different if it went there.

Comment: @Chuck What would it do different? Unless it's used as a **`static`**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a global variable and can be accessed everywhere.

Comment: Not only is it shared by all instances of the class, it's shared by the entire program.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C is a superset of plain ANSI C.  The stuff outside the Objective C interface and implementation are C declarations or code.  In this case a global C pointer variable.  Useful if you need a way for any C function (or any method in any class) to access this NSArray without having it passed as a parameter.

Comment: Actually it's a superset of C++. At least on Mac/iOS.

Comment: @Abhi: No. Any legal C is legal ObjC. The same is not even remotely true of C++ and ObjC.

Comment: I've never had any problems embedding third party C++ code in my Obj-C code, or accessing it from my Obj-C code. They can't subclass each other or anything crazy like that, but for the most part it works.

Comment: @Abhi: Yes, it's possible to use ObjC and C++ code together (this is usually called Objective-C++), but that doesn't make one a superset of the other.

Answer (score 1):

If a variable is declared inside the `@interface` curly braces, then it is an `instance` variable which will exist for every single instance of the class.

If a variable is declared *outside* the `@interface` curly braces, such as the one you see here, then it's just a variable which can be accessed from any file in your program (provided it `#import`'s that `.h` file.

So, anywhere else in your program you can do: `[testArray addObject:foo]` or whatever you want.

This is a feature of `Objective-C` which is rarely used. In fact it's never used by most developers. But it has to exist for compatibility with C/C++ code. It might have been done to (slightly) improve performance, but generally this is something you shouldn't ever do.